# Grid won't fill the entire frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
mainWindow=tk.Tk()
mainWindow.geometry('600x1000')
mainWindow.configure(bg='#000000')



displayFrame=tk.Frame(mainWindow)
buttonFrame=tk.Frame(mainWindow, bg='#000000')



resultLabel=tk.Label(displayFrame, width = 70, height=6, bg='#FFFFFF')
resultLabel.pack()

tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='C',font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#0000FF').grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='÷', font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='%', font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='^', font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=0,column=3,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='7', font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='8', font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='9', font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='-', font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=1,column=3,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='4', font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=2,column=0,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='5',font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='6',font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=2,column=2,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='+', font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=2,column=3,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='1', font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=3,column=0,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='2',font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=3,column=1,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='3', font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=3,column=2,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='0', font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='.', font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=4,column=2,sticky='ew')
tk.Button(buttonFrame,text='=',font=("Arial",40,"bold"),bd=1,fg='#ffffff',bg='#808080').grid(row=3,column=3,rowspan=2,sticky='ns')

displayFrame.pack()
buttonFrame.pack()

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

I am trying to make a GUI calculator using tkinter as a first basic project, while I was making the buttons using grid, I came across this problem, the grid won't fill the entire 'buttonFrame'. Help will be appreciated!

Comment: The grid fills the entire "ButtonFrame", but buttonFrame doesn't fill the entire window